# Password validation with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need a password validation on my form.
I use vuetify validation like this :

```
passwordRules: [
      v => (v && 0 !== v.length >= 10) || 'Min length should be 10',
      v => (v && v.length <= 35) || 'Max length should be 35',
      ],
```

I need a validation if password length is between 1 and 10 because I need to left a blank password.
but the validation work however its 0 or 10.

Comment: You can use [v8n](https://github.com/imbrn/v8n) for this, the validation will be very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Write two rules and remove `required` prop from your input:

```
passwordRules: [
   v => (v && v.length >= 1) || 'Name must be more than 1 character',
   v => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters',
],
```